# yadcf: can exFilterColumn() work with columns which are not visible?

Tags: javascript, yadcf

Please refer to https://codepen.io/louking/pen/vWYqRz

When the datatables columns 5 and 6 are visible, the `exFilterColumn()` call filters the rows as expected, but when these are not visible (as in the codepen), the rows are not filtered.

Can `exFilterColumn()` be made to work with hidden columns?

javascript

```
var $ = jQuery;

var dtoptions = {
    dom: '<"clear">lBfrtip',
    ajax: {
           url: 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/louking/46ef2eb188691817d26c620b1310b37d/raw/bdb7d0e4b78e6ed3e9ca218ecc2feeaa998c9fee/routes.json',
           dataSrc: 'features',
          },
    columns: [
        { data: 'geometry.properties.name' },
        { data: 'geometry.properties.distance' },
        { data: 'geometry.properties.surface' },
        { data: 'geometry.properties.gain', defaultContent: '' },
        { data: 'geometry.properties.links', orderable: false, defaultContent: '' },
        { data: 'geometry.properties.lat', visible: false },
        { data: 'geometry.properties.lng', visible: false },
    ],
    buttons: ['csv'],
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var myTable = $("#runningroutes-table").DataTable(dtoptions);

    yadcf.init(myTable, [
          { column_number: 1, 
            filter_type: 'range_number',
            filter_container_id: 'external-filter-distance',
          },
          { column_number: 2,
            filter_container_id: 'external-filter-surface',
          },
          { column_number: 5,
            filter_type: 'range_number',
          },
          { column_number: 6,
            filter_type: 'range_number',
          },
    ]);

    var lowlat = 39.38160001551371, 
        hilat  = 39.480776692329506, 
        lowlng = -77.54829390576174, 
        hilng  = -77.2825620942383;
    yadcf.exFilterColumn(myTable, [[5, {from: lowlat, to: hilat}], [6,  {from: lowlng, to: hilng}]]);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an epiphany.

Turns out that yadcf needs a place in the DOM to put the filter, so I needed to create a filter container in the DOM to store it. This DOM element can be styled as `display: none`

See the working version at https://codepen.io/louking/pen/EbKYJd

I added the following to the DOM

```
<div class='external-filter' style='display: none;'>
    <span id='external-filter-bounds-lat' class='filter'></span>
    <span id='external-filter-bounds-lng' class='filter'></span>
</div>
```

and updated the yadcf initialization as follows

```
{ column_number: 5,
  filter_type: 'range_number',
  filter_container_id: 'external-filter-bounds-lat',
},
{ column_number: 6,
  filter_type: 'range_number',
  filter_container_id: 'external-filter-bounds-lng',
},
```

Comment: "Turns out that yadcf needs a place in the DOM to put the filter" well... yup :) , another way would be to hide the columns using css (display: none) , but your way is better

Comment: Appreciate the options, and appreciate the package. Hopefully someone gets something out of this.

Comment: And I guess I'm a little surprised that visibile:false isn't implemented with css (display: none). Learn a new thing every day...